# Cambiar tamaño a un fichero via shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

Quiero cambiarle el tamaño a un archivo. Este contiene únicamente un número de dos cifras ([10,99]).

Cuando hago un `ls -l`, me sale que pesa 3B, pero quiero que sea de 2B.

Supongo que esto se debe al salto de línea que se incluye al final de la cadena `\n`. He intentado quitar este mediante `sed` buscando la cadena `\n` y eliminandola: `sed -i 's/\n//d' [file_name]` pero no me funciona.

Alguna idea? Gracias.

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que son 3kb esos 9-10 caracteres?  Segun esta tool deberian ser unos 384 caracteres: http://extraconversion.com/data-storage/characters/characters-to-kilobytes.html... ¿es un archivo de texto plano?

Comment: Perdon, no son 3kb sino 3 bytes. Lo corrigo.

Comment: Esto depende también del sistema de archivos, de la codificación del archivo... hay unos "costos adicionales"  en el tamaño del archivo que no dependen estrictamente del contenido.

Comment: Aver, no hay que ir tan lejos, únicamente estoy haciendo un touch para crear el fichero, y mediante nano escribo dentro un número de dos cifras y guardo. nano añade al final de la línea un salto de línea y supongo que eso también tiene peso, por eso quiero quitarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurren muchas aproximaciones pero evitando poner caracteres y solo ajustando la cantidad de bytes.

El primero y que creo que viene más a tu caso, es usar el parametro `-n` de `echo` para evitar los saltos de línea:

```
$ echo -n "10" > dos_cifras
```

Otro es usar `head` y su parametro `-c`:

```
$ echo '20' | head -c 2 > dos_cifras
$ ls -l dos_cifras
-rw-r--r-- 1 cuauhtli_elizalde staff 2 Feb  9 16:26 dos_cifras
```

Otro es, por ejemplo, si y lo editaste con algún editor de texto, tal vez en el editor viene tu problema y deberías borrar saltos de línea u otros caracteres no imprimibles. El comando de `sed` que pusiste me parece que no funciona para eso ya que al final `sed` añadirá saltos de línea por defecto al buffer.

Un comando interesante es `perl':

```
$ perl -pi -e 'chomp if eof' <nombre del archivo>
```

Y se eliminará el último salto de línea.

Si quieres generar una cantidad de bytes específica sin que te importe el contenido, y sólo el tamaño, puedes utilizar las siguientes aproximaciones.

### *truncate*

El buen `truncate` te permite crear archivos con el tamaño específico pero llenos de "ceros":

```
$ truncate -s 20 dos_cifras
$ ls -l dos_cifras
-rw-r--r-- 1 cuauhtli_elizalde staff 20 Feb  9 16:17 dos_cifras
```

Puedes cambiar el número 20, por lo que quieras. Su contenido tendrá tantos caracteres nulos:

```
$ xxd dos_cifras
00000000: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000010: 0000 0000
```

### *dd*

Con el comando `dd` puedes hacer algo semejante, pero puedes elegir desde el *stdin*, hasta algún archivo:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=dos_cifras bs=1 count=30
30+0 records in
30+0 records out
30 bytes copied, 0.000311 s, 96.5 kB/s
```

Quizás tu problema radicaba o en caracteres no imprimibles, o en que confundías "dos números" con dos caracteres. Es decir la cadena "10,20" tiene dos números, pero 5 caracteres (a.k.a, 5 bytes).

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte, creo que estoy muy cerca. Efectivamente, el contenido deben ser dos caracteres, y no un número de dos cifras.